# SailsJS blueprint matching wrong model

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm having a tricky issue with my models and Sails' automatic blueprint matching.

When I post to one of my endpoints, `/answer/create`, I get a 500 response with validation errors for a different model entirely (the `event` model).

That endpoint for the `event` model would be at `/event/create`, but when I post to that I get a 404.

All of my files were generated with `sails generate [model]` and don't contain any custom Controller routes.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was a result of following this screencast:
http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/09/15/sailscasts-answers-ep1-question-about-using-a-service-to-allow-inheritance-in-a-model/

I was inheriting a baseModel via services into more than one other model, so when I ran `_.merge()`, the changes it made would persist across them both, rendering inconsistencies.

If you want to do this, make sure you use the `_.cloneDeep` method to clone the base model, otherwise `_.merge` will affect it and your blueprints/actions won't work as expected.

In the screencast above, this would make line 12 in the user model look like this:

`module.exports = _.merge(_.cloneDeep(baseModel) { ... });`